# Configured repository failed for Icinga2 on Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, icinga, amazon-linux, icinga2

added the epel release repo and the [Icinga2 repo](https://packages.icinga.com/epel/icinga-rpm-release-7-latest.noarch.rpm) into my instance
based on [this guide](https://medium.com/@robinjohnobrien/icinga-2-installation-part-1-648edd443ea8)

while installing Icinga2 with `sudo yum install icinga2` 
i am getting

```
http://packages.icinga.com/epel/latest/release/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

 One of the configured repositories failed (ICINGA (stable release for epel))
```

is there any other repo for me to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our default release RPMs and repo files use `$releasever`

https://packages.icinga.com/epel/ICINGA-release.repo

Apparently Amazon Linux is using here `latest` as value, instead of `7` or `7Server` like any other RHEL clone.

You should change the baseurl to:

```
baseurl=http://packages.icinga.com/epel/7/release/
```

Amazon Linux is RHEL 7, right?